# Matlab saving variable for each iteration (without using eval)

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, variables, indexing

I would like to achieve this:

```
for k = 1:52
    map = reshape(map,[375 91 223]);
    x[i] = map;

    % create a new variable for each iteration x1,x2,x3,...x52  which stores 'map', 'map' is 375x91x223 size and each iteration produces a new 'map'.
end
```

I am trying to avoid using eval, for now I have thought about writing it to a notepad then importing it back in, but it also takes a lot of time. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about assigning rach iteration to a array index?

```
x = [];

for k=1:52
  map=reshape(map,[375 91 223]);
  x{k} = map;
end
```

Or how about a new struct member for each iteration?

```
x = [];
for k=1:52
  map=reshape(map,[375 91 223]);
  x.(['val' num2str(k)]) = map;
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, using the new struct member for each iteration, if I wanted to access  'val51' within 'x' to plot it, how would I be able to do so. When I try it returns 'undefined function'. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to access like a normal member value:     a = x.val51

Comment: Or simply `x(:, :, :, k) = map`, since `map` is always the same size.